# Nonetype error when accessing dataframe column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series, nonetype

I have a dataframe from a database:

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Data ORDER BY TimeOfEvent"
    DF = pd.io.sql.read_sql(sql, self.cnxn)
```

DF:

```
   EventKeyID   TimeOfEvent  EventConfigId EventCode  EventSymbolId  \
0              20  1.816608e+09              1     12563             50   
1               2  1.816608e+09              5    Log on              1   
2              31  1.816608e+09              1     12563             50   
etc..
```

I try to access the column EventCode as a series using different methods:

```
print(DF.EventCode)
```

and

```
print(DF['EventCode'])
```

but receive the error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I can make it a list using .tolist() but need the column as a series so I can use .str.startswith to find the values beginning with 'Log'.